# How does a C++ compiler manage to emit completely pointless code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, undefined-behavior

Here's a slightly modified version of code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355629/57428):

```
#pragma warning(default:4716)
int recur(int i) 
{ 
   int result;
   result = (i>1 ? i - recur(i/2) : 3);
   // return intentionally omitted
}

int main()
{
    return recur(0);
}
```

Note that `recur()` omits `return` and so its behavior is undefined. Here's what Visual C++ 10 emits for this code:

```
 316: int main()
 317: {
00403940  push        ecx  
 318:   return recur(0);
00403941  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp]  
 319: }
00403944  pop         ecx  
00403945  ret
```

Yes, I know that in case of undefined behavior anything is permitted. But this code is completely pointless and a compiler is a program, so I wouldn't expect pointless things from it.

How does the compiler manage to emit completely pointless code?

Comment: Why are people so quick to downvote and close-vote these types of questions?

Comment: So you expect the compiler to implement an optimization that takes illegal code and generates nothing from it? Refusing to compile sounds like a better behavior to me.

Comment: For the curious, `g++-4.7` emits `xorl %eax, %eax \n ret`
(Intel flavor: `xor %eax,%eax \n retq`). That's under `-O2`, where GCC will typically just drop undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mysticial: The thing with undefined behavior is that the compiler is allowed to expect it not to happen, so what does it generate when it happens is irrelevant. You can't really expect an implementor to optimize code generation for illegal C++ code...

Comment: @sharptooth what is a compiler options did you set ?

Comment: @K-ballo But it's not a crime against humanity to want to understand how a particular compiler handles a case of UB for a particular environment is it? Sometimes, it's actually useful to peak into that black-box and try to understand what's going on.

Comment: Pure speculation: It's not pointless code, it's unfinished code.  The compiler began generating assembly code for the function, which would later most likely be optimized away, if not for the undefined behavior.  Then the compiler ran into the end of the function, where there was no return statement, and said "I don't know what to do now.  What the hell, I'll just output what I've produced so far."

Comment: It can also be helpful to understand that even if a function doesn't return anything it doesn't mean it is pointless, some functions can have side effects. In my opinion, your question is in two parts: "why does the compiler accepts code that doesn't return anything?" and "why does the compiler compile code that is not used in the return statement?"

Comment: Looks to me like the body of `recur` was optimized to nothing and `eax` (return value) was populated with a garbage value (whatever was at `ecx` at the start of `main`.  Looks about like what you asked for.  Not sure why `ecx` in particular.  I know MSC likes to use that for `this` so maybe it saves/restores it often figuring it'll probably be clobbered after a function call.

Comment: why would the compiler do anything for you? if you provide garbage in, it'll spit out garbage out

Answer (score 1):

from compiler viewpoint `return smth;` statement means the simple thing: generate some code to return a result to caller according calling convention (which is for "C", x86/amd64 and trivial types usually means put smth to `eax`/`rax` register). if you miss a `return` this just means to compiler that you won't to generate such code (`mov result, %eax`). usually it leads to a warning (at least): *no return statement in a function returning non-void*. but it could be quite Ok, if function body have `asm` parts which do it instead of compiler... in that (rare) case that warning usually suppressed by #pragma or corresponding command-line option. and yes, in general missed return leads to UB...

Answer (score 1):

As the code has undefined behaviour, the compiler can literally do anything, including generating pointless code.

What most likely happened here is that the compiler faithfully compiled your code and passed it through the optimiser, which did some inlining and constant expression folding.
Using that process on your broken code just happened to result in what you saw.