# Creating a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, geometry

I have been looking at the current problem on Coding Bat:

"We have triangle made of blocks. The topmost row has 1 block, the next row down has 2 blocks, the next row has 3 blocks, and so on. Compute recursively (no loops or multiplication) the total number of blocks in such a triangle with the given number of rows."

I understand what the problem is asking for, and I understand how recursion works. For example, if I am given a recursion function I can work it out by hand and show what the output will be.

The problem is actually creating the recursion function from a given problem, such as this one. I'm not sure how to actually set this up and do it recursively. Are there some sort of rules to follow when actually setting up a recursion problem? I can only find examples that show you how recursion works, not showing you how to actually solve a recursion problem. Any help understanding how to get ready to write the actually recursion algorithm would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to figure what is happen if you put some value for rows (different from 0 or 1). It be interesting what appear if you put a code like that for a system with drastically limited stack space.

Comment: Read the first 1/2 of The Little Schemer. it has step-by-step examples and rules for natural recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly:

1. Always look at the problem and try to find out if it can be divided
   into *subproblems of the same type*. That's a first hint that you can
   possibly use a recursion. Essentially you are looking for a smaller
   instances/versions of an actual problem.

   Recursion takes therefore a top down approach(from the more complex to simpler problem cases).
2. When you can find such cases then you should find out what is the
   relation between the "bigger" case and the "smaller" case  and you
   have your *recursion step*.
3. The final thing is to find out the *terminating condition* or what
   is the smallest or last case where you want to stop.

You probably know about this but if not it might help you.

Comment: That's more of the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`if(rows == 1) return 1;` is useless here.

For the recursion global issue, you must disassemble your problem and find:

1. An exit rule (can be an initial value like in your example, or some exit condition on one of the inputs)
2. A stepping process (what do you have to do with the previous input to get the next one)

And assemble them in a function that calls itself.

Comment: I am just going to remove the code so I can get my actual question across. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

For a `recursion` algorithm,

first design the `base` case, for which the function should start the unwinding of the **stack** or to return the base value.

Then design the algorithm to be actually done, for each of the `non-base` cases

Comment: Understood. When actually designing the algorithm itself, is there a good criteria or set of steps to follow when it comes to the thinking process for recursion in particularly?

Comment: If you are so new in using recurion, just go through my answer here. Its not about any predefined planning. its just the thought process. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355629/recursion-in-c-understand-recursion-example/14356264#14356264

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sumf(int row,int sum){
if(row==0)     //basecase which ends the recursion.
return sum;
else
{sum=row+sum;
return sumf(--row,sum);   // repeating the process.
}}
int main() {
    cout<<"sum is: "<<sumf(5,0)<<endl;
system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

This is the video which make you understand about recursion.(forget about language just focus on concept.)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNJQrtGD1Nc

Comment: I didn't downvote but you are not answering OPs question. He is asking for practical advices on the process of creating recursive algorithm not for another example. I believe he can check the final solution on the coding bat if he wants.

Comment: You don't understand. "_he said if he had given a function he can work it out_" That means he doesn't need a concrete solution, he can work it out when he HAS the solution but it is more or less useless. He wants to know a general approach and tips to getting to that solution.

Comment: Yes, I realize that SO is meant for more specific coding questions, but the reason I posted on here is because I usually end up with some pretty reliable answers.The only reason I put the triangle example is to make my question seem more specific.